# how to run testng through command prompt

Tags: testng

Please let me know how to run the  testng through command line

When I run the following command

```
java org.testng.TestNG TestNG.xml
```

Getting error as below

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
```

which means do we have to compile before running the test?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run TestNG from DOS Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896791/how-to-run-testng-from-dos-prompt)

Answer (score -1):

Please add the complete path of your TestNG Jar in ClassPath of System, then it will work. Like this:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\SourceGear\Common\DiffMerge\;C:\Users\105451\Downloads\Compressed\testng-6.8.7.jar