# How to Run TestNG Tests on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to run TestNG tests (in a contained Java project) from Jenkins but having no luck.

It appears as though the TestNG plugin for Jenkins (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin) only publishes the results of TestNG tests, but doesn't actually run test classes... or am I wrong?

In any case, how do I actually run TestNG tests in a TestNG project with Jenkins, or is that even possible?  Do I have to use a command line statement or batch file (on Windows Server 2008), for example?

Any help much appreciated.

**Note** I tried entering a post-build command line in Jenkins for the project to run TestNG tests but had a hard time with class paths not being found for TestNG.  I posted an earlier question about running TestNG from the command line which I couldn't get working, so I've given up on that route:

[How to run TestNG from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896791/how-to-run-testng-from-dos-prompt)

Comment: You are right about the plugin. How is your java project built? ant, maven, custom script? Tests normally run as a build phase. Also what are the build steps for jenkins?

Comment: It's not built with ant, maven or scripts, it's a TestNG project from JBoss Developer Studio.  So I can run the tests from my own machine, but I want to run the same classes via Jenkins somehow.  I understand there is a way to run TestNG tests as Ant tasks, but I get classpath exceptions and am just confused in general about how to do this.

Comment: Well, it's ant then and JBDS provides it with classpath setting when it runs tests, so should you, either by defining a classpath in the ant script or (better) passing it as an option. -Dtestng.test.classpath="c:/build;c:/java/classes;" When you are able to run your tests with ant command, feed the same to jenkins.

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis I have never used jenkins but as it is a clone of Hudson I believe that there would be a way where you can run shell/batch/ant scripts. So as the first step in the process pls define the classpath i.e, place all your class files and necessary jars in the classpath and run the testNG tests from there.

Comment: @fuzzyanalysis: I am also in a similar situation, I am able to execute my testNG tests, but not sure how to report test failures back to jenkins, in case you could do it, please let me know, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above, please use the following ant script to run TestNG unit tests. Please tweak the below code to meet your requirements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="build" name="Ant Play">
    <property name="classes.dir" value="bin" />
    <property name="report.dir" value="test-output" />
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
         </fileset>
        <pathelement path="${basedir}\${classes.dir}"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="src">
                <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-project" name="build"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" includeantruntime="false" destdir="${classes.dir}">
            <src path="src"/>
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target  depends="build" name="runTests" description="Running tests" >
        <echo>Running Tests...</echo>
        <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpathref="classpath"/>
        <testng outputDir="${report.dir}"
            haltonfailure="true"
            useDefaultListeners="false"
            listeners="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"
            classpathref="classpath">
            <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml"/>
            <!--<classfileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />-->
        </testng>
    </target>
</project>
```

Let me know if you encounter any issues. BTW, please use the Jenkins ant plugin/task to run this script

Comment: Thanks, got your script working finally with an additional <task> declaration to tell ant the classpath to use for testNG.  Cheers.

Comment: could you please provide complete steps to integrate/run testNG testcases with Jenkins.. thanks!

Answer (score 10):

There are two steps to accomplished this task:-

Step 1:-

1. Go to localhost:8080/configure (Jenkins configure section)
2. Now go to JDK section and uncheck Install automatically (If you don't uncheck that then it will download latest java every time whenever it is available, and can cause  for build failed)
3. put JAVA_HOME in name section and jdk home path in JAVA_HOME section

[image]

4. Apply and save

Step 2:-

1. Go to Jenkins and add new Item, also select "Free Style Project" and click on Ok.
2. Click on "Advanced in "Advanced Project Options"
3. Now check option: - "Use custom workspace" and specify your project absolute path in Directory section

[image]

4. Apply
5. Now to go "Build" and select "Execute windows batch command"
6. Here in command column give the file name of your batch file 
   [image]
7. Apply and save

**Now go to the Jenkins and select your Jenkins project and click on Build :)**

Comment: Thanks Shubham!  I only wished that I could have read your answer 2 years ago.  I will note your instructions for future reference (and I am sure others will find your answer useful as this question is getting a lot of views).  Cheers

Comment: Its my pleasure @fuzzyanalysis .. Thanks for your nice and kind words :)

Comment: @ShubhamJain: Well I am also in the similar situation, I am able to run my testNG tests with a shell script which calls ant to trigger tests. Now my problem is - how do I report the test failures back to Jenkins so that Jenkins marks the whole build fail, what I need to do for this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I use gradle to run my testNG tests from Jenkins.
Take a look at [the gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html).

I run the testNG tests using configuration xml files. 
Take a look at [the testNG docs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml).

There is quite a lot to cover so I suggest reading these sources but I'll provide some relevant pieces from one of my configurations.

The relevant parts from my build.gradle

```
tasks.withType(Test) {

    useTestNG {
        useDefaultListeners = true
    }

    options {
        outputDirectory = file('test-report')
        listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
    }

    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    systemProperty "org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output", "false"
    systemProperty "org.uncommons.reportng.title", "Test Report"

    ignoreFailures = true
}


task Smoke_Test(type: Test) {
    description "SmokeTest"
    options.suites("resources/testng-smoketest.xml")      
    ignoreFailures = false
}
```

My testNG xml as referenced above 'testng-smoketest.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Smoke Tests" >
    <test name="BootCheck" parallel="false" thread-count="1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.x.automation.y.tests.smoke.BootCheck" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And from Jenkins, as an 'execute shell' build step run the gradle task, I use gradle wrapper for convenience.

```
./gradlew clean Smoke_Test
```

Ensure you're in the correct directory, 'Smoke_Test' is the name specified in the build.gradle.

You can use the testNG Jenkins plugin for saving your results.

I also recommend using [reportng](http://reportng.uncommons.org/) for nice formatting of your test reports which can also be shown and saved in Jenkins using the HTML Publisher plugin.

Try getting this to run from a CLI on your local machine first, trying to debug when running from Jenkins will drive you crazy.