# How to setup jenkins to run Selenium / Maven / TestNG

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I'd like to be able to run by Jenkins a series of test from Selenium. I've see a lot of topic about the subject but it's not clear to me.

Do I need to call maven to run the project or can I directly call Testng ?

Also do I need with Jenkins to call my project using maven or using Ant ?

What is the best practice. Is there specific plugin that I need.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to call maven to run the project or can I directly call Testng ?

You can call testng through maven or ant. There is no direct runner plugin for Jenkins.

> What is the best practice. Is there specific plugin that I need.

You might need the TestNG plugin to show the results inside Jenkins, but it is optional. Best practice is to use maven or ant.  [You can find a nice ant example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782414/how-to-run-testng-tests-on-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

You can use run TestNG scripts in Jenkins with or without Maven. Maven as a build tool, in my opinion, looks more robust and gives you more flexibility than Ant.

To run pure TestNg script in Jenkins, enter the following in the 'build' section:

```
D:>java -cp "Pathtolibfolder\lib\*;Pathtobinfolder\bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

- Click on Save button.
- Note: The actual path of lib and bin folder need to add the in above
  command.
- After saving the command, Jenkins will build project in predefined
  time, and this command will run using TestNG.
- The result will be stored in custom report HTML file that can be sent via
  email with a small Jenkins configuration