# How schedule Selenium WebDriver script execution

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, selenium-webdriver, testng

Please help me on this. I just want to run my selenium webdriver-Java Script at regular intervals using batch file in windows.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: I just created a .bat file for the testng.xml. and scheduled task using task scheduler. But only shown running of some commands nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using jenkins. I feel it's a best way

Setup Jenkins first by refer my below answer in SO:-

[How to Run TestNG Tests on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782414/how-to-run-testng-tests-on-jenkins)

Then set the setting of scheduler using jenkins as below:-

[How to schedule jobs in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-to-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins)

Hope it will help you :)