# How to run testng.xml in Jenkins ? What are the things required?

Tags: jenkins, scripting, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins, build-automation

I have below things:

I have copied project in my Jenkins server which contains:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat tomcat 4096 Jan 12 06:28 bin

drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat tomcat 4096 Jan 12 06:28 lib

-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat   47 Jan 12 06:28 Run.bat

drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat tomcat 4096 Jan 12 06:28 src

-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat  288 Jan 12 06:28 testng.xml

drwxr-xr-x 6 tomcat tomcat 4096 Jan 12 06:28 test-output
```

I want to run this project in Jenkins. Anyone can pls suggest here?

Note: currently I don't have pom.xml in my project as i just want to run a demo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just publish your test results in Jenkins, use [TestNG plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/testng-plugin). If you also want to run TestNG unit tests, you can additionally use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16828802/10721592) script.

Comment: tomcat@hostname~/scripts/build/pipeline/Jenkins> java -cp "./lib/*:./bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
[TestNG] [ERROR]
Cannot find class in classpath: /usr/share/tomcat/scripts/build/pipeline/Jenkins/src/JenkinsPackage/NewTest.java

Comment: Does it exist in that classpath?

Comment: Yes @biruk .I have given right path. Still it giving same error