# running testng.xml via command line- error Cannot find class in classpath: com.companyname.SSProject.LaunchSSProject

Tags: command-line, testng

I am using following command on command line:

C:\Users\MyScriptDirectory>java -classpath ".;Lib\selenium-2.45.0\libs\testng-6.8.5.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Getting error message:

**[TestNG] [Error]**

**Cannot find class in classpath: com.companyname.SSProject.LaunchSSProject**

I have made following entry in testng.xml:

<class name="com.companyname.SSProject.LaunchSSProject" />

"com.companyname.SSProject" is my package having LaunchSSProject.java file inside it

When I am running the same testng.xml from eclipse, it's working fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following command: `C:\SSProject> java -cp "path/to/your/jar/testng.jar:path/to/your/test_classes" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`

If your `testng.xml` is not in `C:\SSProject` than give the full path to the testng.xml.

SO user Patton has explained this very nicely here - [How to run TestNG from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896791/how-to-run-testng-from-dos-prompt)

**Updated**:

For windows user, following command worked - `C:\Project\Path> java -cp "path/to/your/jar/testng.jar;path/to/your/test_classes" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`

Comment: following worked for me:  
java -cp "Lib\selenium-2.45.0\libs\testng-6.8.5.jar;bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
used ; instead of :

Comment: Great! Updated the answer with the same.

Answer (score 0):

I use testNg on windows, in the windows command prompt the execution, I use the command: `java -cp bin;libs/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`

Result: test run successfully

always on windows: I use git bash command, the command does not execute successfully

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUwNn.png)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -- go to the project folder in command prompt and type:

```
java --class-path "/lib/*;/bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

OR

```
java -cp "lib/*;bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```