# Building the package for TestNG in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I have created a program in eclipse and now I want to make a build so that it can be executed from command line as well. I am having two other files as well in project directory first one is configuration file and second one is input file which can be changed on each run by user.

below is the structure of my project.

```
bin (contains all class files)
lib (contains all jar files)
src
testng.xml
CCBS_SETofDATA.xlsx (Input File)
config.properties (Configuration File)
some other project related file
```

How can I make a build so that user can change these 2 (CCBS_SETofDATA.xlsx and  config.properties) whenever he wants and then run the program using bat file?

Comment: Do you need to have the paths hard coded, or can they be command line arguments?

Comment: it should be command line arguments

Comment: Answer the following answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11897452/6505250 (If not, please tell what is missing.)