# command line testng error- cannot find class in classpath- commandline only

Tags: testng

C:\test-app-java>echo %classpath% C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152;c:\test-ap p\target\test-classes;C:\Users\murkb001.m2\repository;c:\TestNG\;c:\test-app-ja va;c:\test-app-java\bin

c:\test-app-java> java -cp "C:\TestNG\testng-6.11.jar;c:\TestNG\jcommander-1.7.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Error is

C:\test-app-java>java -cp "C:\TestNG\testng-6.11.jar;c:\TestNG\jcommander-1.7.ja r" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

[TestNG] [ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.wdpr.payment.test.AuthorizePaymentTest

Comment: You are not referring to the build folder of your project which contains your compiled classes. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11897452/679824)

Comment: C:\Users\murkb001\Documents\APP_AUTOMATION\app-tests-latest\test-APP>java -cp "C:/TestNG/testng-6.11.jar;c:/TestNG/jcommander-1.7.jar:./bin" org.
testng.TestNG testng.xml
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException

Comment: my classes are present in bin folder, i have added bin folder to classpath also