# "No test suite found. Nothing to run" but testng.xml running properly from eclipse

Tags: java, selenium, testng

While running selenium automation using a bat file, it is showing this error

> No test suite found. Nothing to run

But TestNG is running properly from Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: I think that you're not invoking TestNG properly. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11897452/2553194 and change how you execute TestNG.

Comment: i don't have bin folder created in my peoject, should i created mannually ?

Comment: i think i was doing one mistake. instead of projectLocation while running i was giving ClassPath. now change as  "java -cp %classpath% org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml". Now it is giving error like    "  D:\Myprogram\Emailsent>java -cp D:\Myprogram\Emailsent\bin;D:\Myprogram\Emailsent\lib\* org.testng.TestNG D:\Myprogram\Emailsent\testng.xml
[TestNG] [ERROR]
Cannot find class in classpath: SendEmail.ToCheckPage
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.testng.TestNG.getStatus(TestNG.java:211)
        at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1324)"

Comment: You do not have to create a bin folder. You have to set %classpath% with the directory or directories where TestNG can find your classes and their dependences.

Comment: which class are  u talking about? .java ?

Comment: I'm taking about "Cannot find class in classpath: SendEmail". Where is your SendMail.class file? Usually all your .class files should be packaged in a jar file. You are instructing TestNG to look for them in "D:\Myprogram\Emailsent\bin;D:\Myprogram\Emailsent\lib"  and it seems that they are not there

Comment: yes i don't have .class file

Comment: no bin folder created and in lib folder i put all selenium jar files. where would be my .class file

Comment: Wherever you want. It don't have to be in any specific place. You just have to inform TestNG where to look for it. That's the meaning of a classpath. lib folder is a good place

Comment: we are running testng.xml file, arent we? then what is meaning of giving path of .class file

Comment: Because to run TestNG, you need the compiled classes used to implement TestNG and your own classes that should be tested. You are not running an XML file. You are running a java class  org.testng.TestNG included in a jar file. This class need to execute a method in your java class, that should be in another class file. Both should be accesible in the directory that you established as argument.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i don't have bin folder created, what about that. should i create manually and put some file there?

Comment: Some file? Not just some file, you have to copy there your class file and ALL files imported in your class as well, and files that they use etc. If you have developed your class using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans, you should have already a folder with the required jars. You can point to that folder adding it to the arguments. Something like `java -cp "C:\Eclipse\VishalProject\lib;C:\FolderThatIncludesTestNGjar" ...`

Comment: hi Thanks for every thing. let me clear i don't have bin folder and i don't have any .class file also. i have .classpath and .project file only... now i am going to create one bin folder tell me exactly what files i will paste there.

Comment: How can I tell you "exactly" what files do you need if I haven't programmed your project? If you don't know how java and your IDE work, why are you trying to use advanced tools for testing?

Comment: hey RubioRic. now this problem got resolved. but test is getting failed don't now why when running with batch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using maven for this. I simply changed to java project only and got bin folder created as well. And then convert it to maven project. Now everything is fine. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

The command used to invoke TestNG is incorrect.
Also you can specify classpath with option -cp. So the renewed sample command for you would be

```
java -cp <classpath> org.testng.TestNG <location of testng.xml>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. that is also not working.actually i don't have bin folder created in my project library. will it create any problem.

Comment: this is my batch file content..===>           set projectLocation=D:\Myprogram\Emailsent
cd %projectLocation%
set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib\*
java -cp %classpath% org.testng.TestNG %classpath%\testng.xml
pause

Comment: Are you getting the same error as above ? Is your location of testng.xml correct ?

Comment: yaa same problem

Comment: doesn't have bin folder will create any problem

Comment: i think i was doing one mistake. instead of projectLocation while running i was giving ClassPath. now change as "java -cp %classpath% org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml". Now it is giving error like " D:\Myprogram\Emailsent>java -cp D:\Myprogram\Emailsent\bin;D:\Myprogram\Emailsent\lib* org.testng.TestNG D:\Myprogram\Emailsent\testng.xml [TestNG] [ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: SendEmail.ToCheckPage Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.testng.TestNG.getStatus(TestNG.java:211) at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1324)"

Answer (score 0):

A batch file is nothing but **collections** of commands. Try to run it from **CMD** first and then make a **batch file**. For running **TestNG** from Command-Line, you might wanna follow these steps.

1. After adding TestNG to your project library create one folder in your Project names as lib ( name can be anything ) :
2. Go to "**C:\Program Files\Eclipse\your_eclipse_name\eclipse\plugins**" location and copy **com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar** and **org.testng_6.14.2.r20180216145.jar** file to created folder (lib).

**Note** : Files are **testng.jar** and **jcommander.jar**

Now Launch CMD, and navigate to your project directory and then type :

```
Java -cp C:\Users\User123\TestNG\lib*;C:\Users\User123\TestNG\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Comment: thanks but i don't have bin folder created in my project library.

Comment: this is my batch file content..===>           set projectLocation=D:\Myprogram\Emailsent
cd %projectLocation%
set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib\*
java -cp %classpath% org.testng.TestNG %classpath%\testng.xml
pause

Comment: i think i was doing one mistake. instead of projectLocation while running i was giving ClassPath. now change as "java -cp %classpath% org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\testng.xml". Now it is giving error like " D:\Myprogram\Emailsent>java -cp D:\Myprogram\Emailsent\bin;D:\Myprogram\Emailsent\lib* org.testng.TestNG D:\Myprogram\Emailsent\testng.xml [TestNG] [ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: SendEmail.ToCheckPage Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.testng.TestNG.getStatus(TestNG.java:211) at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1324)"

Comment: Have you performed the steps given in my answer ? and also tell me which testng you are using ?

Comment: ya  i follow your step, in lib folder along with the two jar that u mentioned, i put all selenium jar, testng jar and chrome driver.

Comment: No.!!  Is there any other method to schedule selenium automation

Answer (score 0):

I saw someone mentioning a cannot find classpath problem, had the same issue. I think TestNG changes the classpath variable and moves all class files to /target/classes directory. But if we try to point this path in cmd, it doesnt work. For bat file to run all class files HAVE to be in bin folder. Do the following

Goto Eclipse -> right click on Project ->Properties -> Source tab

Here, change the output folder to bin. Now run the testng xml from eclipse to make sure everything still works.

Then goto bin folder, your class files should now be here. Then run your testng command, should start working.