# Where is the main method located in TestNG framework

Tags: java, testng

I was exploring how TestNG is being executed , it's annotations and XML, but I'm not able to figure out where the main method is! I was referring to the TestNG java document.
https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/

Any resources that mention the content of main() of the framework would be helpful.

Comment: https://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.1.1/org/testng/TestNG.html#main(java.lang.String[])

Comment: There is no need for a main() method in TestNG or JUnit.  They're testing frameworks with their own "run as" options.

Comment: @BillHileman Need a main method for running testng tests from the command line

Comment: @Grasshoppper Was not aware of that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own main method.
Then in your main() method you can call TestNG in that main method like this:

```
TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
testNG.setTestClasses(YourTestClass.class);
testNG.run();
```

Then you can call your main method from the command line that runs TestNG.
TestNG doesn't have a main method, it has only run() method.

This question may have answer that is helpful to you too:
[How to run TestNG from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896791/how-to-run-testng-from-command-line)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The main method of TestNG is located in the [TestNG.java](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/TestNG.java) which is the entry point for running tests and the file is located in

```
package org.testng;
```