# Why TestNG is not running

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am developing Automated web tests using Selenium WebDriver on Java from Eclipse and when I run my testes from java class or from testng.xml file its working and showing me the results.[xml image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dYvk.png) and [results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noMho.png)

Now I want to run testng tests from code upon an event handler, but first I decided to check if testng working from command line or not then I got the following:

```
'testng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable 
program or batch file.
```

Following are the details(configurations) of my laptop.
    Windows 7 Ultimate
    Java [ver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xDTt.png)
    Eclipse [release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwZ8A.png)
    Selenium [ver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krTvd.png)
    TestNG [ver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRPxA.png)
         User Variables > Path
         Value=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin; 
         C:\Users\Ziaullah.PLUMSMEDIA.p2\pool\plugins

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run TestNG from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896791/how-to-run-testng-from-command-line)

Comment: How did you configure testng ?

Comment: I have installed testng by downloading from Eclipse Marketplace and adding the TestNG Libraries in Java Build Path (its working from Eclipse, but having problem from command line as testng not recognized shown.

Comment: http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/how-to-run-testng-xml-webdriver-tests-from-command-line