# How can we run TestNG from command promt

Tags: selenium, testng

I am beginner for TestNG automation scripts when I run my testing.xml in eclipse its working good. But I am not able to run my scripts via command prompt since week and its giving me error as below can some one guide me how can I run my scripts via command prompt.

### testing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="TestBatch">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="./com.automatics.data/com/automatics/data/temp/TV_API_Dev2.xml"/>
    </suite-files>  
</suite>
```

### TV_API_Dev2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="1" parallel="tests" verbose="1" name="EPO_API">

<test name="Tv_E2E">
<classes>
<class name="com.automatics.packages.testScripts.Tv_GCD/>
<class name="com.automatics.packages.testScripts.Tv_VAQ"/>
<class name="com.automatics.packages.testScripts.Tv_SM"/>
<class name="com.automatics.packages.testScripts.Tv_CUId"/>
<class name="com.automatics.packages.testScripts.Tv_SO"/>
</classes>
</test> 
</suite>
```

### Command prompt

```
java -cp "*H:\Automation\automation\Automation" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Comment: This would help you [SO Archive Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896791/how-to-run-testng-from-command-line)

Comment: Hi @AnandGautam i do not have .lib and .bin folders in my project

Comment: Even i tried with all my project folders

Comment: For example: java -cp "*C:/Users/msdfg/Auto/selenium-automation/external/tools/*;
C:/Users/msdfg/Auto/selenium-automation/external/jars/*" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Comment: the link above your provided give me below answer

Comment: java -cp "./lib/*;C:\Users\xyz\IdeaProjects\Example1\out\production\Example1" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Comment: I tried even that but no luck

Comment: @Krish could you please also attach the error messages, you've got?

Comment: Oh is it how many solutions your provided?

Answer (score 0):

I saw your comment

> I do not have `.lib` and `.bin` folders in my project

if you do not have one, then you will have to create one.

Once the `TestNG` plugin is downloaded from Eclipse marketplace.

1. After adding TestNG to your project library create one folder in your Project names as lib ( name can be anything ) :
2. Go to "`C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse-java-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins`" location and copy **com.beust.jcommander_1.72.0.jar** and **org.testng_6.14.2.r20180216145.jar** file to created folder (lib).

**Note:** Files are `testng.jar` and `jcommander.jar`

3. Now Launch CMD, and navigate to your project directory and then type :
   **Java -cp C:\Users\User123\TestNG\lib*;C:\Users\User123\TestNG\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml**

That's it !