# Execute tests sequentially in TestNG

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, testng

I have multiple test classes, which should be executed sequentially. I created `testng.xml` file with following content.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="MyTestSuite1" verbose="2" parallel="methods" thread-count="1">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="utils.TestNGListener"></listener>
    </listeners>

    <test name="Regression" parallel="false" verbose="2">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.LoginTest" />
            <class name="test.ClearTest" />
            <class name="test.SendMessageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I created `main()` method for project to provide entry point.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    TestNG testNG = new TestNG();

    String xmlFileName = "testng.xml";
    List<XmlSuite> suite = (List<XmlSuite>)(new Parser(xmlFileName).parse());
    testNG.setXmlSuites(suite);

    testNG.run();
}
```

I am not sure, how to execute test suite in specified order, got error message.

> Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot find
>   class in classpath: test.LoginTest

Output of `tree` command:

```
C:.
├───.idea
│   └───libraries
├───META-INF
├───out
│   └───artifacts
├───resources
│   └───leanftjar
├───RunResults
│   └───Resources
│       ├───Snapshots
│       └───User
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   ├───hu
│   │   │   │   └───mysoft
│   │   │   ├───jar
│   │   │   │   └───META-INF
│   │   │   ├───META-INF
│   │   │   ├───unittesting
│   │   │   └───utils
│   │   └───resources
│   └───test
│       └───java
│           └───test
├───target
│   ├───classes
│   │   ├───hu
│   │   │   └───mysoft
│   │   ├───leanftjar
│   │   ├───unittesting
│   │   └───utils
│   ├───generated-sources
│   │   └───annotations
│   ├───generated-test-sources
│   │   └───test-annotations
│   ├───maven-status
│   │   └───maven-compiler-plugin
│   │       └───compile
│   │           └───default-compile
│   └───test-classes
│       └───test
└───test-output
    ├───All Test Suite
    ├───junitreports
    └───old
        └───All Test Suite
```

Comment: You are seemingly referencing a class `test.LoginTest` in your Regressiontests. Does this class exist?

Comment: Yes, sure, it is located in `test` named package.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to check the very basics, you never know :)

Comment: Maybe the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600898/testng-error-cannot-find-class-in-classpath) can help.

Comment: @Ben : No, I am looking for example, where there are more than one test classes.

Comment: @plaidshirt - Can you please show us your project directory structure ? Also please let us know where in the project directory structure does your test classes reside and where does the class that houses the `main()` method reside in.

Comment: Please run `tree` command on your project and show the same

Comment: can you show part/all of `LoginTest` class?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan : Test classes are under `src\test\java\test`. All other classes: `src\main\java\com\mysoft`.

Comment: @TarunLalwani :I updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your code. By default classes that reside under `src/main/java` don't have visibility into classes that reside in `src/test/java`. So when you create the TestNG instance in your main() method from `src/main/java` TestNG is trying to load classes from the same and since it cannot find them it's throwing the exception.

To fix this problem please move the class that contains your main() method into a package under `src/test/java` and try again. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

In order to execute TestNG tests you should mark test method with `org.testng.annotations.Test` class

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod() {
```

For using `testng.xml` see [example](https://gist.github.com/randomsync/1629341)

> ```
> // 1. To run with testng.xml file, uncomment this one, comment 2
> testng.setTestSuites(Arrays.asList("testng.xml"));
> ```

For executing with tests order use `setPreserveOrder`:

> ```
> testng.setPreserveOrder(true);
> ```

Comment: I edited `main()` method, but got error: `Cannot find class in classpath: test.LoginTest.`

Comment: Test classes are under src\test\java\test. All other classes: src\main\java\com\mysoft.

Comment: @plaidshirt - Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a hard requirement to run these steps in order, for your test to pass, it seems that they should be implemented internally in the test.

```
@Test
public void doIt() {
   login();
   clearMessage();
   sendMessage();
}
```

With the appropriate checks for success is going to fail as a unit, not hide the actions from the test maintainers, and provide better debugging output in the event of a test failure than "three tests stitched together as one".

Comment: Yes, but in this case I use simple method calls from a test class.