# How can I avoid Error: org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath: ScenarioTestscript.ScenarioOne

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

I am trying to run test using TestNG with the maven project here. I have refreshed, cleaned, and reinstalled testNG, then imported the maven projects, but I am getting the following exception:

```
    [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.4.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot find class in classpath: ScenarioTestscript.ScenarioOne
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:75)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:67)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:54)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:576)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:766)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:164)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:250)
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:324)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:376)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:1011)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:98)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

How can I avoid this exception?

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600898/testng-error-cannot-find-class-in-classpath

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TestNG ERROR Cannot find class in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600898/testng-error-cannot-find-class-in-classpath)

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird error I have had so many times working with testNG. Here is the solution :

1. Right click on project and go to Run as
2. Select maven clean
3. Now go to Project from Eclipse menu bar (File, Edit, ...)
4. Click on Clean
5. Select your Project
6. Click on Clean

[image]

that's it. Hope this will help many.